# Problemas al mostrar imágenes desde el servidor

Tags: php, javascript, sql, mysqli, iis

Tengo un script de php que consulta imágenes de un qnap "192.168.10.129", y  al momento de cargar imágenes me presenta dos problemas:

1- Solo lo ve internet explorer de forma local. 
2- No me despliega las imágenes si accedo desde otra pc.

El servidor web esta configurado desde IIS, aquí le dejo mi código:

```html
<html>
 <head>
 <style type="text/css">
 
 .table0{
position: absolute;
top: 20%;
left: 2%;
padding-top: 0%;
padding-bottom: 0%;
padding-left: 5%;
display: block;
overflow-y: scroll;
height: 50%;
z-index: 3;

}
 </style>
 
  <title>Prueba de PHP</title>
 </head>
 <body>


<?php
$serverName = "192.168.10.134";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"*********", "UID"=>"**", "PWD"=>"***");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

$sql = "SELECT TOP 200 Itemcode, Itemname, PicturName FROM OITM ";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
echo "<table border = '1' class = 'table0' > \n"; 

echo "<tr><td>Itemcode</td><td>Itemname</td><td>Picture</td></tr> \n";
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    echo "<tr><td>$row[Itemcode]</td><td>$row[Itemname]</td><td><img src='file://192.168.10.129/sapshared/FOTOS/KennedyDB/$row[PicturName]' height = '100' width = '100' ></td> </td></tr>"; 
}
echo "</table> \n"; 


sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
?>


 </body>
</html>
```

Ya intenté colocando http, pero no me lo acepta porque solo es un storage.

Comment: se supone que el dentro del echo va la imagen cierto? , entonces no veo que este concatenando nada  para mostrar, las variables de php parecen que estan solo en string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tendrás que configurar IIS para que sirva la carpeta de red `//192.168.10.129/sapshared/FOTOS/KennedyDB/` via http en alguna url, lo mas sencillo sería montar la carpeta dentro de donde tenes el php

Asumiendo que el php está en `c:\Inetpub\wwwroot` creamos una carpeta link localmente que apunta a la carpeta qnap (seguramente necesites permisos de admin)

Desde el command line:

```
 mklink /d "c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\images" "\\192.168.10.129\sapshared\FOTOS\KennedyDB\"
```

Si falla de esta forma tal vez debas primero montar la carpeta qnap en un drive (asignarle una letra de disco, ver primer link al final) y luego hacer el `mklink` a la carpeta raiz del drive.

Luego en el php cambiamos el `file://` por la ruta relativa al php

```
<img src='file://192.168.10.129/sapshared/FOTOS/KennedyDB/$row[PicturName]'
```

cambia a

```
<img src='images/$row[PicturName]'
```

nota: el mklink es solo posible en windows 10, 7, 8 y Vista

**Referencias**

Montar un qnap a un drive:

https://www.qnap.com/en/how-to/tutorial/article/mapping-a-shared-folder-to-a-windows-computer

Crear una carpeta link:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink#BKMK_examples

Comment: Gracias alo, me pondré en esa, la configuración es algo compleja, porque el php esta corriendo en el servidor 192.168.10.16  el sql server está en el 192.168.10.134 y como notaste el qnap está en el 10.129

Comment: acabo de configurar el qnap como ftp, pero para entrar debo colocar credenciales de dominio

Comment: y por qué ftp? lo único que hay que hacer es que el IIS tome los archivos del qnap como locales, montarlos en una carpeta o en un drive mapeado. luego se transmiten por http como el php

Comment: Hice lo que me dijiste y me sale este error en el iis 0X80070005, Se me olvido decirte, mi sistema operativo es Windows server 2016, Cannot read configuration file due to insufficent permissions

Comment: Tendrías que actualizar la pregunta con la información nueva, pegar el error completo al final junto a los pasos que seguiste

Comment: ok, lo que me escribiste arriba está bien, porque el browser si ve los archivos solo que ahora seria cuestion de proveer permiso a la carpeta

Comment: buenísimo, por los permisos fijate este hilo en inglés https://stackoverflow.com/a/10457630/1423096 si ves que se complica abris una nueva pregunta (con el tema permisos) y lo vemos