# Como subir imágenes de una carpeta en red a un sitio WEB

Tags: html5, asp.net-mvc-5, imagen, iis

Tengo un sitio WEB de ASP.NET MVC 5, me interesa subir a este sitio algunas imágenes que tengo en una carpeta a parte del proyecto, el problema erradica en que el atributo al colocar la dirección especifica de la imagen en el src de la etiqueta img, dichas imágenes no se cargan, ya que están fuera del ámbito del proyecto.

Me gustaría saber que pudiera hacer a nivel de configuración en el proyecto y/o en el IIS para poder servir las imágenes desde esa carpeta a mi pagina web

Comment: fijate si te sirve https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/163136/81450

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas crear un directorio virtual que apunte hacia el sitio en red, en las opciones avanzadas del directorio virtual elije el usuario que tenga los permisos adecuados de acceso a dicho directorio.

Ahoa, para llamar a las imágenes de ese directorio, es igual como si las tuvieras en la misma aplicación.

Comment: Excelente, esa era la solución, muchas gracias.

Comment: de nada hermano, que te vaya excelente con la programación :D